# Spring Boot: At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hello everyone,
I have a problem when I run my project

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

I don't know how to fix it.I saw some same topic and They said this problem in file pom.xml. But I don't see anything wrong in my file pom.xml. So Can somebody help me
This is my Code
File pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>3.3.7</version>
```

DemoApplication

```
package com.example.demo;


 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication

public class DemoApplication  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args); 

}
```

Model with @Entity

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

public Contact() {
    super();
}

public Contact(int id, String name, String email, String phone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

 public String getEmail() {
    return email;
 }

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
 }
```

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Your SpringBootApplication relies in `package com.example.demo;` and your entity in package `com.example.model;` . Spring cannot find your entities, unless you specify it explicitly e.g. via `@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.model")`

Answer (score 0):

You have in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But you don't have any classes with `@Entity` annotation defined. You need at least one of those to successfully create the Entity Manager. If not remove the above dependency.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I have classes with @Entity in Model.. I added in my post Can you fix my proplem

Answer (score 0):

Your SpringBootApplication relies in package `com.example.demo;` and your entity in package `com.example.model;` . Per Default `@SpringBootApplication` will try to look into its package and below. It cannot find your entities as they are in a different package, unless you specify it explicitly e.g. via

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.model")
```